# Efficient way to simulate full outer join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, outer-join

According to Google search: since MySQL does not support full outer join, it could be simulated via union and/or union all. But both of these either remove genuine duplicates or show spurious duplicates.

What would be correct and efficient way?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989730/help-me-out-with-this-mysql-full-outer-join-or-union) seems relevant but couldn't get the answer of it.

Comment: see this link : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and a RIGHT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.b_id = tableB.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tableA RIGHT JOIN tableB ON tableA.b_id = tableB.id
WHERE tableA.b_id IS NULL
```

There is also some information on Wikipedia about this topic: [Full outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join).

The Wikipedia article suggests using a UNION in MySQL. This is slightly slower than UNION ALL, but more importantly it won't always give the correct result - it will remove duplicated rows from the output. So prefer to use UNION ALL instead of UNION here.

Comment: This is exactly the solution mentioned by @haim evgi (via page link). Thanks.

Comment: How do you scale this answer up for N tables? That is, how would you emulate a FULL OUTER JOIN on four tables and up?