Select from 2 tables in the last 30 days, return 0 if null/not exist
I'm trying to obtain data from 2 tables in the last 30 days in MySQL 5.7 to create a graph. The idea is to display the invoice total and payment total per day in a bar graph for comparison. Therefore I need the date of transaction (for payment and/or invoice) and totals for that day.
Need to select the following:
INVOICES table

Sum of invoice_total per invoice_date

PAYMENTS table

Sum of pay_amount per pay_date

There are entries in the PAYMENTS table where the date doesn't exist in the INVOICES table and vice versa. When we come across these it should return a 0 amount.
select STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS TransDate, ROUND(sum(payments.pay_amount),2) as PmtTOTAL, ROUND(sum(invoices.invoice_total),2) as InvTOTAL 

FROM invoices

LEFT JOIN payments on invoices.invoice_no = payments.invoice_no 

WHERE payments.active='1' and invoices.active='1' and payments.pay_type <> 'Desconto' and payments.pay_type <> 'AJUSTE' and payments.pay_type <> 'ESTORNO' 
and STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 

GROUP BY invoices.invoice_date 

ORDER BY payments.pay_date asc; 

Here's my fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/IjLM7Kyn
PS: fiddle is getting a group by error which I'm not getting locally.
Thanks in advance!
The query provided by xQbert has allowed me to come up with a better graph, reason why it was never posted initially. Basically this graph gives the user a quick overview of all billings and payments per day in the last 30 days. xQbert's query almost has it.


see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc to solve the error.

you should GROUP BY the field that you are using in your query (and use more line-separators when typing a query, because horizontal sliders are not very helpful.), see: https://dbfiddle.uk/-6r4OId2

Hi Luue. On 2024-09-16 it shows: Total: 850.00 and INVTotal:850.00. It should be: Total:850 InvTotal: 440

Hi Ronalde, you should use DATE when you want to store a date, not varchar(30) ....

You stated: "there are entries in the PAYMENTS table where the date doesn't exist in the INVOICES table and vice versa. When we come across these it should return a 0 amount."  You will need to use a FULL OUTER JOIN; but since MySQL doesn't support it you'll need to have two queries one right join one left join to get all records and union them together in addition to the issue Luuk pointed out.

that's a bit beyond my knowledge. Do you have an example I can loot at?

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447215/efficient-way-to-simulate-full-outer-join-in-mysql

I appreciate your efforts, but I can't get it working.

Thinking about this some more you have some other issues.  if you have records in invoices not in payments what date should those records have when you select from payment date?   I'll play around with your sample data some more to better understand the problem.  But as it stands I also see a problem when your LEFT JOIN is making your query behave like an inner join since the null records from payments get excluded due to the where clause evaluations

I'd encourage a Fiddle example using just a few records to show the problem you're having  the extra data is adding unneeded noise.  Also; using that sample data show your expected results. It will help clairify issue.

It's possible to have more records in the payments table than the invoices table. For example. If a client makes multiple payments towards the same invoice on different dates.  On the other hand if multiple invoices are outstanding without payments, there would be more records in the invoices table.

So looking at your comment earlier On 2024-09-16 it shows: Total: 850.00 and INVTotal:850.00. It should be: Total:850 InvTotal: 440.  Why do you expect a total of 850?  There are no invoices 51 listed in the payment table. I can get it to be 0 and 440 with these modifications.  https://dbfiddle.uk/jv_2vEty and if we make those invoices numbers on the 3 records be the 51, then we can get it to 850 and 440.  but there's just so many questions i'm not sure where to begin.

I appreciate the effort!  Looks like it's almost there.   There are THREE payments dated 2024-09-16 that add up to $850 and ONE invoice dated 2024-09-16 that totals $440.

yeah but the date isn't how they join.  those records show invoice numbers of 10,8,9.. not 51.  So they dont' relate and they need to based on invoice_no right?  you can't just assume dates match and they are for the same invoice...

So the confusion here was your example SQL is joining on invoice number when I don't think you want that at all...

Recognizing this is mySQL 5.7 there are no Common table expressions: So I'm stuck using inline views.
Things to note:

Summed each table's data by date and amount
then since there are missing dates on both tables; we need to FULL OUTER JOIN; but that too isn't an option so we use Payments LEFT JOIN Invoices UNION INVOICES LEFT JOIN Payments to get all records back

Giving us: This https://dbfiddle.uk/OcdGkhbP
SELECT PAYDATE TRANSDATE, TOTAL, INVTOTAL
FROM (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS PAYDATE
     , ROUND(SUM(payments.pay_amount),2) as TOTAL
  FROM payments
  WHERE payments.active='1' 
    and payments.pay_type not in ('Desconto', 'AJUSTE', 'ESTORNO')
    and STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
  )  P
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS INVDATE
       , ROUND(SUM(invoices.invoice_total),2) as INVTOTAL
  FROM invoices
  WHERE invoices.active='1' 
    and STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y') between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
  ) I
on P.PAYDATE=I.INVDATE

UNION ALL 

SELECT INVDATE TRANSDATE, TOTAL, INVTOTAL
FROM (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS INVDATE
       , ROUND(SUM(invoices.invoice_total),2) as INVTOTAL
  FROM invoices
  WHERE invoices.active='1' 
     and STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y') between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
  ) I2
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS PAYDATE
     , ROUND(SUM(payments.pay_amount),2) as TOTAL
  FROM payments
  WHERE payments.active='1' 
    and payments.pay_type not in ('Desconto', 'AJUSTE', 'ESTORNO')
    and STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
  ) P2
   on I2.INVDATE=P2.PAYDATE
 WHERE P2.PAYDATE is null

With these results:
+------------+---------+----------+
| TRANSDATE  |  TOTAL  | INVTOTAL |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 2024-08-20 |  200.00 | 1050.00  |
| 2024-08-21 |  280.00 | 280.00   |
| 2024-08-22 |  450.00 | 450.00   |
| 2024-08-23 |  830.00 | 830.00   |
| 2024-08-26 |  200.00 | 690.00   |
| 2024-08-27 |  450.00 | null     |
| 2024-08-28 |  680.00 | 680.00   |
| 2024-08-29 |  110.00 | 110.00   |
| 2024-09-02 |  830.00 | 830.00   |
| 2024-09-03 |  940.00 | 940.00   |
| 2024-09-04 |  300.00 | 610.00   |
| 2024-09-05 | 1070.00 | 790.00   |
| 2024-09-06 |  235.00 | 235.00   |
| 2024-09-09 |  420.00 | 420.00   |
| 2024-09-10 |  500.00 | 500.00   |
| 2024-09-12 |  250.00 | 250.00   |
| 2024-09-16 |  850.00 | 440.00   |
+------------+---------+----------+

Note some of the logic changes:

We filtered by invoice date for 1 month (Differnet)
we filtered payments by date for 1 month (Same)
we join based on date not invoice number (Different)
We display payment date if one exists, otherwise we use invoice date. (combining invoice/payment in one column if no payment different)

So the question becomes:
What invoice/payments are you after when referencing date:
either within the past 30 days;
only those with a payment in the past 30 days which excludes invoices without payments then.
Unable to use Common table expressions due to version of MySQL (Supported in 8) which would make this MUCH easier to read.

PERFECT! I can't thank you enough for your hard work and effort.  Much appreciated!

I thought I saw a comment about something not working earlier; but didn't have a chance to get back to it.  I assume that is resolved at this state..  Good luck!

My bad. It is working. Just missed the order by part. Thanks again!

Reason for Error in dbfiddle:
The server is setup to use explicit notations must use 'as' when aliasing, must have all items in select not aggregated in the group by etc..  you don't have such restrictions on your environment.
QUESTIONS:

If there is no payment; what date should be displayed?  Since you're pulling payments and you may have a invoice without a payment
Since multiple payments may occur on an invoice we need max of invoice amount since there are not MULTIPLE invoices with the same number.
why do you expect the payment total for 9/16/ to be 850?  There are no invoices in payment table with invoice number 51.

ASSUMING:

Invoice is UNIQUE and must always exist before a payment

MODIFICATIONS:

Changed date to invoice date instead of payment date on select.
used max on invoice total a sum will result in amount*number of payments
used coalesce on payments incase there are 0 amounts to replace the NULL
Modified where clause/join criteria.  As it stood your where clause was negating the left join making it behave like an inner join.
Modified pay_type to use not in instead of multiple <>'s
group by invoices.invoice_date.

My Fiddle example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/r7Fkh6zW
SELECT 
       -- Using invoice date since payment date may not exist.
       STR_TO_DATE(invoices.invoice_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS fmtDate
     , ROUND(max(invoices.invoice_total),2) as INVTOTAL 
       -- using coalesce to show 0 instead of NULL 
       -- using max since an invoice can only have 1 amount and fanning of records will cause a 
       -- SUM to increase invoice total. 
     , coalesce(ROUND(sum(payments.pay_amount),2),0) as TOTAL
FROM  invoices 
LEFT JOIN payments 
  on invoices.invoice_no = payments.invoice_no 
  -- Moved these limits to the join so as left join doesn't behave like inner join
  and payments.active='1' 
  and payments.pay_type not in ('Desconto', 'AJUSTE', 'ESTORNO')
  and STR_TO_DATE(payments.pay_date,'%d-%m-%Y') between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
WHERE invoices.active='1'   
GROUP BY invoices.invoice_date 

Giving us:
+------------+----------+---------+
|  fmtDate   | INVTOTAL |  TOTAL  |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 2024-09-02 |    90.00 |  830.00 |
| 2024-09-03 |    90.00 |  940.00 |
| 2024-09-04 |   320.00 |  590.00 |
| 2024-09-05 |   340.00 |  780.00 |
| 2024-09-06 |    45.00 |  235.00 |
| 2024-08-07 |   150.00 |    0.00 |
| 2024-08-08 |   120.00 |    0.00 |
| 2024-08-09 |   380.00 |    0.00 |
| 2024-09-09 |   240.00 |  420.00 |
| 2024-09-10 |   400.00 |  500.00 |
| 2024-09-12 |   250.00 |  250.00 |
| 2024-09-16 |   440.00 |    0.00 |
| 2024-08-20 |   450.00 | 1050.00 |
| 2024-08-21 |    50.00 |  280.00 |
| 2024-08-22 |    50.00 |  450.00 |
| 2024-08-23 |   230.00 |  830.00 |
| 2024-08-26 |   490.00 |  650.00 |
| 2024-08-28 |    60.00 |  680.00 |
| 2024-08-29 |   110.00 |  110.00 |
+------------+----------+---------+

Unsure what expectations are so I don't know how to validate these changes.
And now if we update payments invoice number for 10,9,8 to be 51 as indicated in comments you can see the 850.  so was it bad data?
https://dbfiddle.uk/6Q6aoQ2w

I see you applied https://i.sstatic.net/f38s3k6t.png and commented: This is the graph I am trying to create. Blue bar shows billings for the day and the green bar payments for the day. PS: This is the query in your fiddle.  So to me the issue is 1 Bad data: and 2 if you're trying to show paymenets for eahc invoice/payment by DAY as well; then we need to join on day? or show payment date?  So the question yet remains: .  What date should be displayed in the results?  invoice date if there is no payment otherwise show the payment date?

Now that I re-read that do you not care about coorlations between invoices and payments?  Do you Just want to know for a given day what was the total amount invoiced and also the payments received each day?  if that's the goal then you dont' need to join on invoice number, but instead join on payment date and invoice date.

Maybe: https://dbfiddle.uk/fFCeuevQ using last example: but now I have a concern that we may have payment dates w/o invoices dates. and a full outer join may be needed

LATEST joining on Dates only for join and handling the full outer join using a union https://dbfiddle.uk/ylhdVD_z and you see what I mean about what date to use now.  Use invoice date if it exists, otherwise use payment date or vice verse?  we can see 8-7 to 8-9 have no payments but still show up. but 8/27 has a payment but no invoices on that date.  The initial confusion for me was your query was joining on invoice number when it seems to have no bearing on what you're after.  If this is right I should probably start a different answer as this one is way wrong joining on invoice_no to begin.

THere's a simpler way to do this now that I know what you're after.  This is approach is way over complicated.  sum the amounts by date for each table using a common table expression (CTE/with) . Then use left join from invoice to payment union payment to invoice where invoice date is null.

For a moment I thought the query was perfect, but there's an amount of 4,150 on 2024-08-23 what is incorrect. What does the easier approach look like?

likely due to the max I was using.  I'll see if I can get the easier one working.  I'm haivng trouble with how "explicit" I'm having to be in this version of mySQL

Would be ideal if I could get 3 variables: fmtDate, Total and InvTotal. That way the graph is ready for the data. Thank you

May have to continue this a bit later.  The psudo code for this is :Create a CTE for payments and one for invoices summing by date.  Then use the P LEFT JOIN I on the dates UNION I LEFT JOIN P opn dates where P.payment_date  is null.  But for some stilly reason it's not liking my CTE syntax so i'm duplicating code using subqeries which I don't like.  Have to be sure to include your limiting criteria as well; but the concept is "simple" now that I know what you're after.

Much appreciated xQbert!

"The server is setup to use explicit notations must use as" -- I can't parse that. Can you reword it?

It might just be a version thing: it' been a long time since I was in 5.7.  But I'm having to alias using as instead of just "invoice.invoice_date I_Date" as well as the explicit group by has been enabled so all non-aggregated columns must be in group by.
